# Como setear variable AngularJS con una variable C# en la vista

Tags: c#, angularjs

Ninguna de estas formas me funciona e intente

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" value="@Model.valor2">
```

Ni

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" ng-value="@Model.valor2">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Ninguna de cuales formas? Pulsa en [edit] y añade lo que has probado

Comment: @Anthony Robert Cardenas Vilcap ademas de los consejos te Pikoh de preferencia que el código sea texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta utilizando la directiva [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) para inicializar el valor de un modelo desde la vista en angularjs:

```
<div ng-init="model1 = '@Model.valor2'">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model1">
</div>
```

Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.model = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-init="modelo ='hola mundo'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="modelo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que desde el controller de angular deberias invocar invocar un action usando `$http` para tomar el valor que retornar el codigo servidor en `c#`

Una view mvc no aplica a un controller de angular, son incompatibles, si usas angular entonces no usas `.cshtml`, usas solo `.html` que seria la view de angular

La mejor union entre `c#` y `angular` es usando `web api`

[Hands On Lab: Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)

Como observaras en el articulo se tiene una base que arma la pagina principal usando una vista de mvc usando `cshtml`, pero luego el resto lo recupera usando `$http` invocando la `web api`